# How to achieve a different folder structure in a Wordpress Theme like Roots Sage Starter Theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, webpack

I'm a beginner developing Wordpress Themes, and I have missed some paradigms on PHP for the last years since I'm not a full time PHP programmer, I haven't use frameworks or libraries besides Slim.

I'm trying to add Webpack to a new Wordpress theme, but stack all the files I need in the root folder is lack of organization.

So, I'm wondering how does Roots Sage Starter Theme accomplished its folder structure, It seems that they use their own installer, but I don't know whats the purpose of this or even how it works, as far as I can see the installer is just there in order to choose between the CSS frameworks

How can I integrate Webpack changing the folder structure of a new Wordpress theme?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You should read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your first question.

Comment: I have read it, what did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a comprehensive studying of Sage, I got to the following conclusions:

- The sage-installer package is executed right after the project is created with composer, and it's purpose has nothing to do with the folder structure
- The sage-lib is necessary in order to use a class extending the illuminate/container class Container, making available the use of a singleton implementation, in which you attached a extra things to the constructor.
- The extra things are configs, with the help of Wordpress add_actions function, the class can override where Wordpress search for the template files and register styles/scripts

So, after looking the repository, if you omit the part of the blade templates, you can use webpack in an agnostic way.

Like this repository https://github.com/benjavazquezlucero/alchemist-sage